# Is giving sometimes funny answer in good or bad tone?

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

I wonder if adding a little bit of humor to Stack Overflow answers will be good or bad. For the serious, let's say - mainstream - part of questions, probably not. But there are sometimes questions so strange and so poorly prepared, that I can hardly resists in giving some funny, absurd answers.

As an example, look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359618/how-to-create-a-table-in-c-sharp-console-application) and my answer. If someone asks in two-three clauses how to write a game or something like that, and do not improve the question, it will for sure remain closed. But are such funny answers littering Stack Overflow or not? Should be such an answers upvoted? Downvoted? Deleted?

In my opinion it can made SO more friendly and human, but at the other hands, this kind of answer do not add any value and can be even treated as an impolite by the OP. So I wonder what do you think about it.

Comment: I managed to get away with a couple of humorous answers on SO. My rule of thumb is "can be funny, but never derogatory to the questioner". That's why I never answer bad questions with jokes, the risk of achieving (2) is too high.

Comment: Funny is OK, so long as it **answers** the question. And of course, needs to "be nice", as @FrédéricHamidi alluded.

Comment: You could have done a better job in the specific case.  You could have (1) fetched wood, (2) used an axe to cut the wood, (3) hammers & nails and so on... You should have completed the answer.  For more fun you could have chosen to: _Marked the wood with a micrometer, marked it with chalk, and cut it with axe_.

Comment: Ah! it should have been _Measured the wood with a micrometer, ..._

Comment: There's lots of great questions and answers out there that utilize humor. Here are some famous examples:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193953/flash-cs4-refuses-to-let-go
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1157054

Comment: Humor has obsoletely no place in SO.  I would never post a hummus (or even sarcophagus) ensnare or cement, and I wood virtuously devote anyone who wood.  I'm amazoned you're even Timken of dis.

Comment: Your linked question has disappeared, which makes it hard to see the funny in it. :-)

Comment: So would [this kind of joke](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576430/how-to-find-the-fibonacci-sequence-with-c/13577106#13577106) answer, where I take a poor question and answer it with a solution that is technically correct, yet ill advised, count as a good or bad example of a joke answer?  (It was something I did on one of my first months here, and one of my first 'serious' metaprograms)